# Flutter Snapshot.hasError throws type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: flutter, snapshot

Grabbing a json.

```
Future<Pwa> _futurePwa;
Future<Pwa> getPwa() async {
      debugPrint("getPwa start");
      String urlX = 'https://' + urlOne.text;
      category ='PWA';
      locale = 'se';
      strategy = 'mobile'; 
      String baseUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=$urlX&category=$category&strategy=$strategy&locale=$locale";
      http.Response response = await http.get(baseUri);
      if (response.statusCode == 429) {
        debugPrint('PAUSE QUOTA EXCEEDED: ${response.statusCode}'); //OK
      }
      else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        debugPrint('Response status: ${response.statusCode}'); //OK
        debugPrint('Response body:');
        debugPrint(response.body);
        return Pwa.fromJson(await json.decode(response.body));
      }
      else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load API data.');
      }
    }
```

```
Container (
                    child: new FutureBuilder<Pwa> (
                          future: _futurePwa,
                          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Pwa> snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData) {

                              debugPrint("Futurebuilder<Pwa> buildpart");
                              debugPrint("Test snapshot content: ${snapshot.data
                                  .toString()}");
                              debugPrint(return Text('Res: ${snapshot.data.lighthouseResult.finalUrl}');
                            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              debugPrint("T9-e ${snapshot.error}");
                              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                            } else {
```

snapshot.hasError throws:
**type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'**

I can see that this might happen if you do some integer division but Im not.
This normally runs through, but my futureBuilder produces error and throws error back if I run int multiple times. Does this mean that there are type errors in the parsing getPwa() or is this because I use the future again?

Comment: When doign the parsing of Pwa there must be a parameter that is a double but the json file parse it as an int and throws the error, let's say in your from json you havea parameter called double number =  json['value'] and json['value'] gives you back a number, but is an int and not a double, try json['value'].toDouble(), can you post the Pwa class model?

Comment: It's 855 rows, so here's a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/DbzNGJiG

Comment: By the error it means it's the other way around, you're trying to give an int parameter a double value like int score or int weight (line 463) or other int, are you sure they're all numbers without decimals?